# PL/SQL- Query to get Start and End date Based on column Values

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a list of employees existence data by month (Exist='T', Not Exist = 'F') and data looks like following.

```
DepNo   Empno   Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
---------------------------------------------------------------
1234    100     T   T   T   T   T   T   T   F   F   F   F   F
1234    101     T   T   T   T   F   F   F   F   F   F   F   F
1234    102     F   F   F   F   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T
1234    103     F   F   F   F   T   T   T   F   F   F   F   F
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to get the Start and End dates for each employee. For e.g Employee 100 start date is 01-Jan-2015 (since in Jan he exist) and End date as 31-Jul-2015 (since employee was termintaed in August

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DepNo   Empno   Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec StartDt EndDt
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1234    100     T   T   T   T   T   T   T   F   F   F   F   F   1-Jan-15 31-Jul-15
1234    101     T   T   T   T   F   F   F   F   F   F   F   F   1-Jan-15 30-Apr-15
1234    102     F   F   F   F   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   1-May-15 31-Dec-15
1234    103     F   F   F   F   T   T   T   F   F   F   F   F   1-May-15 31-Jul-15
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am using Oracle 11g. Can some one help me to achive this.

Comment: See [select...case (SQL)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) and [select... case (PL/SQL)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/case_statement.htm).

Comment: Nivas, select....case won't work. because with select....case 1st-row returns enddt as 30-Nov-2015 but I need 31-Jul-2015. Correct me if i am looking something wrong

Comment: You *can* use a single SQL with select case but that would become too complex. If you can use PL/SQL, I recommend that. I will try writing the SQL and post it as an answer if I am able to get a decent one.

Comment: You would also have to be much clearer about your assumptions. Can you have the same employee going back and forth between `T` and `F` multiple times?  Can an employee have only `F`s?  What do you do for such cases? Is it assumed that the month is for the year `2015`?

Comment: It would also be nice of you to post what you have tried so far. Including your attempt at using `select ... case`.

Comment: I have no idea why I did this, but here you go - I have added an answer. Note that I strongly recommend against doing this and using PL/SQL or some other programming language for the logic. Also I have not tested this (yet). I will update based on my testing (or delete my answer).

Comment: sstan, I don't have a case for an employee with only 'F' and I always have data for a year so either it should be 2015 or for a given year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare environment.

```
create table tab1(depno number,empno number, jan char(1),feb char(1),mar char(1),apr char(1),may char(1),jun char(1),jul char(1),aug char(1),sep char(1),oct char(1),nov char(1),dec char(1));
insert into tab1 values(1234,100,'T','T','T','T','T','T','T','F','F','F','F','F');
insert into tab1 values(1234, 101,'T','T','T','T','F','F','F','F','F','F','F','F');
insert into tab1 values(1234, 102,'F','F','F','F','T','T','T','T','T','T','T','T');
insert into tab1 values(1234,103,'F','F','F','F','T','T','T','F','F','F','F','F');
```

Run this query

```
select tab1.*,t3.startd,t3.endd from tab1, (select depno,empno,min(to_date('2015.'||monthh1||'.01','yyyy.mm.dd')) as startd, max(add_months(to_date('2015.'||monthh1||'.01','yyyy.mm.dd'),1)-1) as endd from (select t1.depno,t1.empno,decode(monthh,'JAN',1,'FEB',2,'MAR',3,'APR',4,'MAY',5,'JUN',6,'JUL',7,'AUG',8,'SEP',9,'OCT',10,'NOV',11,'DEC',12,-1) monthh1,statee from (select * from tab1 unpivot (statee for monthh in(jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec))) t1) t2 where statee='T' group by depno,empno)t3 where tab1.depno=t3.depno and tab1.empno=t3.empno order by tab1.depno,tab1.empno
```

ENJOY.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this. Note that I strongly recommend against doing this and using PL/SQL or some other programming language for the logic. <strike>Also I have not tested this (yet). I will update based on my testing (or delete my answer)logic</strike>. Works. SQLfiddle added.

(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/30fc1/12):

```
 select e.empno, 
       1 start_day, 
       (case when EXTRACT(month FROM e.StartDt) > t.start_month 
             then EXTRACT(month FROM e.StartDt) 
             else t.start_month end) start_month, 
       EXTRACT(year FROM e.StartDt) start_year,
       to_date(1  || '-' ||
       (case when EXTRACT(month FROM e.StartDt) > t.start_month 
             then EXTRACT(month FROM e.StartDt) 
             else t.start_month end) || '-' ||
       EXTRACT(year FROM e.StartDt), 'dd-mm-yyyy') start_date
from employee e, 
     (select empno, 
             decode(Jan, 'T', 1, 
             decode(Feb, 'T', 2, 
             decode(Mar, 'T', 3, 
             decode(Apr, 'T', 4, 
             decode(May, 'T', 5, 
             decode(Jun, 'T', 6, 
             decode(Jul, 'T', 7, 
             decode(Aug, 'T', 8, 
             decode(Sep, 'T', 9, 
             decode(Oct, 'T', 10, 
             decode(Nov, 'T', 11, 
             decode(Decm, 'T', 12, 0)))))))))))) start_month
       from employee) t
where e.empno = t.empno
```

You can get end date based on this idea. Again, please don't use this if you can avoid.

Answer (score 0):

> Hello just tried very simplified way of resolving this issue. Hope it
>   helps. Let me know for any issues.

```
    ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YYYY';

    SELECT a.EMPNO,
      to_date('01/'
      ||COALESCE(DECODE(a.dec,'F',NULL,'12/'),DECODE(a.nov,'F',NULL,'11/'),DECODE(a.oct,'F',NULL,'10/'),DECODE(a.sep,'F',NULL,'09/'),DECODE(a.aug,'F',NULL,'08/'),DECODE(a.jul,'F',NULL,'07/'),DECODE(a.june,'F',NULL,'06/'),DECODE(a.MAY,'F',NULL,'05/'),DECODE(a.april,'F',NULL,'04/'),DECODE(a.march,'F',NULL,'03/'),DECODE(a.feb,'F',NULL,'02/'),DECODE(a.jan,'F',NULL,'01/'))
      ||extract(YEAR FROM sysdate),'DD/MM/yyyy') STR,
      TO_DATE('01/'
      ||COALESCE(DECODE(a.dec,'F',NULL,'12/'),DECODE(a.nov,'F',NULL,'11/'),DECODE(a.oct,'F',NULL,'10/'),DECODE(a.sep,'F',NULL,'09/'),DECODE(a.aug,'F',NULL,'08/'),DECODE(a.jul,'F',NULL,'07/'),DECODE(a.june,'F',NULL,'06/'),DECODE(a.MAY,'F',NULL,'05/'),DECODE(a.april,'F',NULL,'04/'),DECODE(a.march,'F',NULL,'03/'),DECODE(a.feb,'F',NULL,'02/'),DECODE(a.jan,'F',NULL,'01/'))
      ||extract(YEAR FROM sysdate),'DD/MM/yyyy') ED_DT
    FROM
      (SELECT 10 AS DPT,
        1 EMPNO,
        'T' AS jan,
        'T' AS feb,
        'T' AS march,
        'T' AS april,
        'T' AS may,
        'T' AS JUNE,
        'T' AS jul,
        'F' AS aug,
        'F' AS sep,
        'F' AS oct,
        'F' AS nov,
        'F' AS DEC
      FROM dual
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 10 AS DPT,
        2 EMPNO,
        'T' AS jan,
        'T' AS feb,
        'T' AS march,
        'T' AS april,
        'F' AS may,
        'F' AS JUNE,
        'F' AS jul,
        'F' AS aug,
        'F' AS sep,
        'F' AS oct,
        'F' AS nov,
        'F' AS DEC
      FROM dual
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 10 AS DPT,
        3 EMPNO,
        'F' AS jan,
        'F' AS feb,
        'F' AS march,
        'F' AS april,
        'T' AS may,
        'T' AS JUNE,
        'T' AS jul,
        'T' AS aug,
        'T' AS sep,
        'T' AS oct,
        'T' AS nov,
        'T' AS DEC
      FROM dual
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 10 AS DPT,
        4 EMPNO,
        'F' AS jan,
        'F' AS feb,
        'F' AS march,
        'F' AS april,
        'T' AS may,
        'T' AS JUNE,
        'T' AS jul,
        'F' AS aug,
        'F' AS sep,
        'F' AS oct,
        'F' AS nov,
        'F' AS DEC
      FROM dual
      )A;

-------------------------------OUTPUT-----------------------------------------

EMPNO     STR              ED_DT
1   01/07/2015  01/07/2015
2   01/04/2015  01/04/2015
3   01/12/2015  01/12/2015
4   01/07/2015  01/07/2015

-------------------------------OUTPUT-----------------------------------------
```